# Ivy failing to resolve

Tags: java, ivy

I'm new to Ivy, so this might have been already covered, but I don't know enough to know. My search came up empty to find similar experiences.

So, when I first pulled down the entire project and when library references are updated, I sometimes get an unresolved dependencies warning. It is seemingly on random libraries.

For example, I just added commons-codec-1.9 to a certain project, and other projects in the working set use 1.6 and 1.7. When running the grand build script, all of the sudden for 1.6 and 1.7 the "configuration [is] not found":

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6: 'runtime'. It was required from org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.2 compile
[ivy:resolve]       :: commons-codec#commons-codec;1.7: configuration not found in commons-codec#commons-codec;1.7: 'runtime'. It was required from org.apache.solr#solr-core;4.0.0 compile
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Now, I'm not entirely sure what that means. What I do know is that within my Ivy cache (`C:\Users\me\.ivy2\cache\commons-codec\commons-codec`), the ivy-1.6.xml and ivy-1.7.xml files are much smaller than ones that resolve. For example, `ivy-1.6.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0">
    <info organisation="commons-codec"
        module="commons-codec"
        revision="1.6"
        status="release"
        publication="20140107114252"
        default="true"
    />
    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>
    <publications>
        <artifact name="commons-codec" type="jar" ext="jar" conf="default"/>
    </publications>
</ivy-module>
```

Whereas any other artifact that did resolve has much, much more information in it.

The catch is that I can copy another developer's ivy-x.y.xml from their cache, and then it downloads the JAR properly, and everything works. What do I need to do to not have this happen every time libraries are updated or added?

Comment: It might also happen that your dependencies have dependencies which are not able to be resolved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ivy resolve failing for some users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660333/ivy-resolve-failing-for-some-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your cache is stale. This can happen if you make lots of changes to your ivy or ivysettings file.

I recommend adding an extra target that you can use to periodically force a fresh download of your projects dependencies:

```
<target name="clean" description="Cleanup build files">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-all" depends="clean" description="Additionally purge ivy cache">
    <ivy:cleancache/>
</target>
```